# Kendo DropDownList select value after AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I try to select DropDownList value after data from AJAX come, but my solution doesn't work
Here is my code:

```
function openWindow(e) {
    var wdw = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    wdw.open();
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = '@Url.Action("BindingList", "AttributeBinding")' + "?formId=" + dataItem.FormId;
    grid.dataSource.read();
    $("#title").html(dataItem.FormTitle);
    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "- please select -",
        dataTextField: "StringValue",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("PopUpBind", "AttributeBinding")',
                    dataType: "json",
                },

            },
            requestEnd: function () {
                $("#dropdown").data('kendoDropDownList').value(dataItem.MultiLinkerProductAttributeId);
            }
        }
    });

};
```

When DropDown is loaded I can set #dropdown value by Web Browser console, but this same code doesn't work with requestEnd function in dataSource

Comment: Try to use dataBound: instead of requestEnd: and you should isolate your function dataBound: functionname(e);

Comment: @CarlosMartins that is it, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event [requestEnd](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/requestend) in the [DataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) is fired when the request of the data is completed *but* the data doesn't have to be bound to the widget. Since the selection refers to the widget ([DropDownList](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist)) you should use [dataBound](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/events/databound)

Your code would be something like:

```
function openWindow(e) {
    var wdw = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    wdw.open();
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = '@Url.Action("BindingList", "AttributeBinding")' + "?formId=" + dataItem.FormId;
    grid.dataSource.read();
    $("#title").html(dataItem.FormTitle);
    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "- please select -",
        dataTextField: "StringValue",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("PopUpBind", "AttributeBinding")',
                    dataType: "json",
                },

            }
        },
        dataBound: function(e) {
            this.value(dataItem.MultiLinkerProductAttributeId);
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: event handler name schould be written case sensitive, otherwise it will not work.
 

dataBound: function(e) {
            this.value(dataItem.MultiLinkerProductAttributeId);
        }

Comment: @WojciechIłowiecki, you are right! I will edit the answer. Thanks